# Entity framework code first for the subset of DB tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, code-first

I would like to add new module (project) to my solution and to use entity framework code first only for subest of my database tables. I'm using ADO.NET with stored procedures in other modules. I plan to split tables from db in the future, but for now it is not possible (tables have no relations to other tables but are used by old modules) I'm not sure if it is good practise to do it in this way and I would like to ask for help.

- is it possible to use EF code first for subset of the tables of my DB?
- how to initialize these tables with code first? I found only solutions to drop whole
  db if model doesn't match and recreate new DB. I need drop and recreate only
  tables that are used in my project
- is it good practise to use more approaches of the db access to one db?
- do you see some problems in this approach? Now I see problem with concurency and data consistency ( if old module will operate with this tables in another approach )

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, it is. On one of our projects, we had database with store procedures which we migrated to use EF. But not at once. It had taken some time so we used Store procedures whit ADO.NET as well as EF together.

2) I must say I'm not sure about this. We had database already created with only few changes. But you could created tables by yourself.

3) I think better would be to call stored procedures from EF and use it on whole projects if you need them. But using both, ADO.NET and EF is ok, if you have reasons.

4) Why it would be problem if you will use transactions?

Comment: thank you for answer. You probably use database first approach. I would like to transform to code first. Problem what I see is with synchronization of contexts. If you already have some EF context with cached data and you change something through ADO.NET approach, context is not up to date and that I see like problem.

Comment: No no. We used code first with existing database. It's new since EF 6.1/6.2 dunno. I still think that if you will use transactions with necessary isolation level it could work well. But maybe it'll result in performance problems.